# How can I play html5 player video in cefsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I used cefsharp in c# winforms
under is the my code

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrower();
        }

        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

        private void InitBrower()
        {
            //Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("allow-running-insecure-content", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-speech-input", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-usermedia-screen-capture", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("debug-plugin-loading", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("allow-outdated-plugins", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("always-authorize-plugins", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-web-security", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-npapi", "1");
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://videojs.com/city");  
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
```

but the video in that link does't not work
I think maybe cefsharp doesn't support html5 player, because copyright trouble

Is there any way to support html5 player in cefsharp?

Comment: Html5 is supported, the browser only supports free and open audio and video codecs see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multimedia-audiovideo for more details.

Comment: The webm demo at https://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files/ should play directly in the browser if you use the video element example at the bottom.

Comment: Um I don't know I understand very well now, the video what I want to play in cefsharp is mp4 type and using html5player. Is this possible to play in cefsharp winform? @amaitland

Comment: Mp4 is not supported.

Comment: So, is there a way for individuals who are not official support to build mp4 separately?
@amaitland

Comment: Mp4 is a container format,  typically comprising of h264 for video and AAC for audio, both require licences. The links at the bottom of https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multimedia-audiovideo discuss building CEF with support for proprietary codecs, link to docker scripts to simplify the process, other details. If it's just a handful of videos I'd suggest converting them to webm format.